# How to select a another tab when jquery response using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When form fade out then select another tab which is also jquery tab

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_string,

    //GET method is used
    type: "POST",

    //pass the data         
    data: data_string,

    //Do not cache the page
    cache: false,

    //success
    success: function (html) {
        //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
        if (html != "") {
            //hide the form
            $('.form').fadeOut('slow');

            // here the function is not working...

            $(function () {
                $("#tabmenu").tabs("#content", {
                    effect: 'ajax',
                    current: 'active',
                    initialIndex: 1
                });
            });    
        } else {
            alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a quick note: There's no need to wrap stuff in a dom ready function inside an AJAX handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
 $("#tabmenu").tabs("#content", {
   effect: 'ajax',
   current: 'active',
   initialIndex: 1
 });
});
```

Change your code from that above to that below.

```
$("#tabmenu").tabs("#content", {
  effect: 'ajax',
  current: 'active',
  initialIndex: 1
});
```

I guess it can't fire your tabs because the DOM, in this very moment, is loading.

Comment: Do you have Firefox & Firebug installed? Or something else to view the Javascript error, you have to be getting? Please post it.